# Auto scroll to bottom of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How is it possible to automatically scroll to the bottom of a UIViewController once the page is opened?

Currently when I open the page its scrolled all way to the top.. But I need it at the bottom as that is where the latest messages are

Heres the swift for the table view:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dataArr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messages") as! UITableViewCell        
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    let message = cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UILabel
    let name = cell.viewWithTag(101) as! UILabel
    let data = self.dataArr[indexPath.row] as! [String:AnyObject]
    message.text = " " + String(describing: data["message"]!) + " "
    name.text = String(describing: data["name"]!)

    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var mapStr = ""
    let data = self.dataArr[indexPath.row] as! [String:AnyObject]
    let message = String(describing: data["message"]!)
    let array = message.components(separatedBy: "\n") as! [String]
    let arrayLoc = message.components(separatedBy: "Location: ") as! [String]
        if arrayLoc.count > 0 {
            mapStr = arrayLoc[1]
        }
    print(mapStr)
    if mapStr.count > 0 {
        self.open(scheme: mapStr)
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Could be a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378009/how-do-i-automatically-scroll-in-a-table-view-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378009/how-do-i-automatically-scroll-in-a-table-view-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i automatically scroll in a table view? (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378009/how-do-i-automatically-scroll-in-a-table-view-swift)

Comment: I have looked at this solution and it doesn't seem to work for me :( It throws back errors

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: noOfRows, section: 0)
yourTableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableView.ScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
```

Comment: If you want the tableview to scroll when the view appears then add it to viewwillappear method but remember viewwillappear calls everytime, other options is at viewdidload method.

Comment: @OliverFerris Well if you have the data, then you can put this this `viewDidApear` else if you are fetching data after going to respected ViewController then after getting all data, then you can put that code there.

Comment: I see! But now when I try to pass in the noOfRows Im getting an unresolved Identifier :(

Comment: it's noOfRows - 1

Comment: @OliverFerris replace your tableview array count with noOfRows.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me in Swift 4

I have overidden the viewDidAppear function of my UITableViewController class.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let scrollPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height)
    self.tableView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: false)
}
```

Thanks to this post
[Scroll all the way down to the bottom of UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886817/scroll-all-the-way-down-to-the-bottom-of-uitableview) for the answer, note that question's not quite the same, they scroll down on reloadData rather than the screen appearing.